# Navigation stack not behaving the way I want it to

Tags: ios, swift, xcode

I have a question about my navigation stack. It isn't behaving the way I want it to.
I have a RequestDetailsViewController that I want to present off of my RequestsViewController. However, when I do a show or a present:

```
let navigationController = NavigationController(rootViewController: RequestDetailsViewController(request: serviceRequest))
self?.show(navigationController, sender: self)
```

```
<ProHomeTabBarViewController 0x7f9152043800>, state: appeared, view: <UILayoutContainerView 0x7f9151520c40>
   | <UINavigationController 0x7f9152059000>, state: disappeared, view: <UILayoutContainerView 0x7f9151529530> not in the window
   |    | <ProDashboardViewController 0x7f9141569c70>, state: disappeared, view: <UIView 0x7f9151459a10> not in the window
   | <UINavigationController 0x7f915189be00>, state: appeared, view: <UILayoutContainerView 0x7f9151466390>
   |    | <RequestsViewController 0x7f91448231e0>, state: appeared, view: <UIView 0x7f915152fda0>
   | <UINavigationController 0x7f9151890c00>, state: disappeared, view: <UILayoutContainerView 0x7f915146ec00> not in the window
   |    | <ProDashboardViewController 0x7f915146bc90>, state: disappeared, view: (view not loaded)
   | <UINavigationController 0x7f91518a6e00>, state: disappeared, view: <UILayoutContainerView 0x7f9151473450> not in the window
   |    | <PayoutsViewController 0x7f9151470fa0>, state: disappeared, view: (view not loaded)
   | <UINavigationController 0x7f915206a000>, state: disappeared, view: <UILayoutContainerView 0x7f915152d3c0> not in the window
   |    | <ProProfileViewController 0x7f9151475690>, state: disappeared, view: (view not loaded)
   + <NavigationController 0x7f9153163a00>, state: appearing, view: <UILayoutContainerView 0x7f9151787320>, presented with: <_UIPageSheetPresentationController 0x7f9151789210>
   |    | <RequestDetailsViewController 0x7f915389c000>, state: disappeared, view: <UIView 0x7f9151790070> not in the window)
```

As shown above, it is presenting off of the root ProHomeTabBarViewController. However, I want it to present off of the RequestsViewController so that I can reference it when I dismiss the RequestsDetailsViewController. Can you let me know if this is the wrong approach or something different should be done in this situation?

When I do a push off of the navigation controller, it adds correctly to the RequestsViewController Navigation stack as shown below:

```
<ProHomeTabBarViewController 0x7fc066039600>, state: appeared, view: <UILayoutContainerView 0x7fc065589d40>
   | <UINavigationController 0x7fc06604ce00>, state: disappeared, view: <UILayoutContainerView 0x7fc065595520> not in the window
   |    | <ProDashboardViewController 0x7fc06561e030>, state: disappeared, view: <UIView 0x7fc06560d390> not in the window
   | <UINavigationController 0x7fc055841000>, state: appeared, view: <UILayoutContainerView 0x7fc05562a7e0>
   |    | <RequestsViewController 0x7fc06559dd10>, state: appeared, view: <UIView 0x7fc055639530>
   |    | <RequestDetailsViewController 0x7fc056077a00>, state: disappeared, view: <UIView 0x7fc065499d60> not in the window
   | <UINavigationController 0x7fc055851000>, state: disappeared, view: <UILayoutContainerView 0x7fc055630490> not in the window
   |    | <ProDashboardViewController 0x7fc05562d520>, state: disappeared, view: (view not loaded)
   | <UINavigationController 0x7fc05681ce00>, state: disappeared, view: <UILayoutContainerView 0x7fc061213100> not in the window
   |    | <PayoutsViewController 0x7fc055632830>, state: disappeared, view: (view not loaded)
   | <UINavigationController 0x7fc06703f600>, state: disappeared, view: <UILayoutContainerView 0x7fc065627dd0> not in the window
   |    | <ProProfileViewController 0x7fc0612158e0>, state: disappeared, view: (view not loaded)
```

In fact, this happens whenever I present anything off of the child controllers of ProHomeTabBarViewController. Also if I wrap the ProHomeTabBarController in another parent routing controller and try to present off of one of the child view controllers, the new controller presents off the the routing controller as shown below.

```
<ProRoutingViewController 0x7fd69b428540>, state: appeared, view: <UIView 0x7fd68b667ed0>
   | <ProHomeTabBarViewController 0x7fd68c822600>, state: appeared, view: <UILayoutContainerView 0x7fd68b6691b0>
   |    | <UINavigationController 0x7fd69d82d600>, state: disappeared, view: <UILayoutContainerView 0x7fd69e018360> not in the window
   |    |    | <ProDashboardViewController 0x7fd69b53bfc0>, state: disappeared, view: <UIView 0x7fd69b724c10> not in the window
   |    | <UINavigationController 0x7fd69b855a00>, state: disappeared, view: <UILayoutContainerView 0x7fd69b431580> not in the window
   |    |    | <RequestsViewController 0x7fd69e01f300>, state: disappeared, view: <UIView 0x7fd69b7443a0> not in the window
   |    | <UINavigationController 0x7fd69b854200>, state: appeared, view: <UILayoutContainerView 0x7fd69b4362b0>
   |    |    | <ProDashboardViewController 0x7fd69b433340>, state: appeared, view: <UIView 0x7fd69b573040>
   |    | <UINavigationController 0x7fd68c815600>, state: disappeared, view: <UILayoutContainerView 0x7fd68b65a4f0> not in the window
   |    |    | <PayoutsViewController 0x7fd69b438650>, state: disappeared, view: (view not loaded)
   |    | <UINavigationController 0x7fd68c814600>, state: disappeared, view: <UILayoutContainerView 0x7fd68b670160> not in the window
   |    |    | <ProProfileViewController 0x7fd68b66d530>, state: disappeared, view: (view not loaded)
   + <NavigationController 0x7fd69c01a000>, state: appearing, view: <UILayoutContainerView 0x7fd69b584b10>, presented with: <_UIPageSheetPresentationController 0x7fd69b5676c0>
   |    | <CompletedJobViewController 0x7fd69c01c200>, state: disappeared, view: <UIView 0x7fd69b5921f0> not in the window
```

Comment: What is `self` in that code snippet?

Comment: self is RequestsViewController